# insert the result into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i need to insert this result in one table

```
declare @i int

set @i=(select max(id) from finalaccountdetails)
(

select ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY DateTime_Executed )+@i as id ,

 DateTime_Executed, ReportName,Region, 'IM Account' as Account_Name_Level_1,'IM' as Management_Group_Name, 
 replace(
       replace(C
       ,'%5c','\')
      ,'%2B','+') as Account_code_level_1 ,count(*) as NumberofExecution from preaccountdetails

group by DateTime_Executed, ReportName,Region,c
having c like '%-%' or c like '%2B%')
```

when i use to keep this as subquery it is throwing an error at declare.

kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY DateTime_Executed )+@i as id ,

 DateTime_Executed, ReportName,Region, 'IM Account' as Account_Name_Level_1,'IM' as Management_Group_Name, 
 replace(
       replace(C
       ,'%5c','\')
      ,'%2B','+') as Account_code_level_1 ,count(*) as NumberofExecution
into #TempTbl
 from preaccountdetails

group by DateTime_Executed, ReportName,Region,c
having c like '%-%' or c like '%2B%')
```

If you want it add it everytime. Create a table with the schema of the select clause, the use the below query:

```
   insert into [Newtable]
   select ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY DateTime_Executed )+@i as id ,

     DateTime_Executed, ReportName,Region, 'IM Account' as Account_Name_Level_1,'IM' as Management_Group_Name, 
     replace(
           replace(C
           ,'%5c','\')
          ,'%2B','+') as Account_code_level_1 ,count(*) as NumberofExecution
     from preaccountdetails

    group by DateTime_Executed, ReportName,Region,c
    having c like '%-%' or c like '%2B%')
```

Comment: this will be used only once,but  i need to insert into same table on multiple times as per my requirement